# What would be a 'Pythonic' way to extract certain properties from one object hierarchy into another?

Tags: python

Say I have complex type like this:

```
class MyForm(wtforms.Form):
  firstname = wtforms.TextAreaField()
  lastname = wtforms.TextAreaField()
```

The TextAreaField can be coerced to a `str`() which contains HTML.  It has a property called `data` that contains the raw data.  It also has a property called `label` that contains the HTML meant for the display label.  So that's three values that I want to extract from this complex type.

What might be a pythonic way to create a new object containing only the properties that I want?

Something like....

```
f = MyForm()
... populate f ...
x = {}
for k, v in f:
  x[k] = {'html1': str(v), 'data': v.data, 'html2': v.label}
```

I know that is all wrong, help!

Later, I want to be able to say:

```
print x.firstname.data
print x.firstname.html1
print x.firstname.html2
```

Comment: Does MyForm have an iterator that iterates over the fields that are targets for this new object that we are creating?   Are these fields "variable", or is it "hard wired" that MyForm always has firstname and lastname, and only these two?

Comment: It has `iteritems` on it.  However, I wanted this to be generic somewhat, and not get too wrapped up in WTForms specifics.  To answer your question, in my case, MyForm could be other forms with different fields. All the fields have the same properties (label, data and can be coerced to str) (WTForms is here: https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/wtforms/form.py)

Comment: In C# land, we can do this pretty easily using a dynamic combined with a lambda in a LINQ select expression.  I was wondering if there was something similar.  In Python, I know we can invent a type and populate it using a for-loop.  I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do this without resorting to all of that.

Comment: Have you considered making class MyForm(wtforms.Form) derive from `dict` as well (multiple inheritance)? Then you can add members like firstname, lastname as dict items. Since it is a `dict` type object you can use it like any other Python dictionary.

Comment: I guess what I'm hoping to learn in this is a way to map one object to another without changing the source type.  Isn't there a lambda or something we can write to do this?

Answer (score 1):

How about just writing an adapter class?

```
class TAFAdapter(object):
    def __init__(self, taf):
        self.taf = taf
    @property
    def data(self): return self.taf.data
    @property
    def html1(self): return str(self.taf)
    @property
    def html2(self): return self.taf.label
```

Then all you have to do is this:

```
class MyForm(...):
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstname = TAFAdapter(wtforms.TextAreaField())
        ...
```

Depending on your needs, you could have TAFAdapter directly instantiate the `TextAreaField`, or you could genericize it to work for other form fields, ...